# How to add html, with click listeners on elements, dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to add a form to a page when the user clicks a button. I am making a string of that html and then adding it to the div using jQuery. (I've read somewhere this is not the best method, so please tell me an alternative).

However, the problem is this - The new html that I am adding has a button with id `id1`. The script that I try to call, does not get called when I do this-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#id1").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

This may be happening because I have written this inside document.ready(), and by the time document gets ready, no element with id `id1` exists. How can I mitigate this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate the event.Here [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is used to attach an event handler function

```
$("body").on("click","#id1",function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: there are so many duplicate of event delegation OP should have just closed